# Escrever um ficheiro com o conteúdo de um array

Tags: java, arquivo

Tenho um array de `char` *grid* e quero escrever um ficheiro com o seu conteúdo. Eis o código que fiz:

```
public static String getGrid() {
    String text = String.valueOf(grid);
    return text;
}


public static void Escreve() {

    String imprime = getGrid();
    System.out.println(imprime);

    File newFile = new File("C:/Users/Miguel/Desktop/newFile.txt");
    if (newFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("já existe");
    } else {
        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter(newFile);
            BufferedWriter buffW = new BufferedWriter(fileW);
            buffW.write(imprime);
            buffW.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

O array `grid` originalmente teria o seguinte aspecto:

```
grid = {{'W','S','W', 'W'}, {'W','W','_','E'}}
```

o resultado final pretendido do ficheiro criado é:

```
WSWW
WW_E
```

a primeira "função" transforma o array de char para array de string e a segunda cria um ficheiro novo e deveria escrever o  conteúdo do array, mas o que obtenho no ficheiro criado é o seguinte: [[C@2424d3cc

Alguma maneira de resolver o problema?

Comment: Pode adicionar um exemplo desse conteudo do array grid?

Comment: já atualizei o post

Comment: Isso ai não é um array unidimensional de char, é um array de arrays, não vai funcionar mesmo. Você quer concatentar tudo desse array numa string?

Comment: mas é possível escrever um ficheiro com um array multi-dimensional?

Comment: Não sei o que você quer fazer com esses dados, não tem como eu te responder isso. Mas se quiser juntar tudo numa string só, precisa de um laço

Comment: eu editei novamente o post com o resultado pretendido no ficheiro criado

Comment: E o tamanho desse grid? Sempre será [4][2]? Creio que seja mais facil salvar com um separador sem converter pra string, senão depois vai ter o mesmo trabalho pra ler o arquivo.

Comment: o tamanho é definido pelo utilizador cada vez que o programa é iniciado, mas depois disso, sim o tamanho mantém-se no resto do programa.

Comment: Então, talvez a melhor forma de salvar não seja essa que você quer, e sim, utilizando um separador, pra facilitar depois recuperar os dados.

Comment: o que quer dizer com utilizar um separador?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como se trata de um array que armazena outros arrays do tipo `char`, essa forma não vai funcionar. Você vai precisar transformar os arrays mais internos em string, para depois salvar no arquivo.

Veja seu código num exemplo com as modificações:

```
public static void Escreve() {

    char[][] grid = { { 'W', 'S', 'W', 'W' }, { 'W', 'W', '_', 'E' } };

    File newFile = <caminho do arquivo>;

    if (newFile.exists()) {

        System.out.println("já existe");

    } else {

        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter(newFile);
            BufferedWriter buffW = new BufferedWriter(fileW);

            for (char[] g : grid) {
                buffW.write(String.valueOf(g) + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            buffW.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

A saida no arquivo de texto é:

```
WSWW
WW_E
```

Repare que além do laço, eu utilizei `System.getProperty("line.separator")` para que quebrasse linha, como mostrado no seu exemplo, independente do sistema operacional executado.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda